# CalendarServer on MediaTemple's VE

Tags: mediatemple, calendar

I'm trying to set up CalendarServer 2.3 on a MediaTemple ve server running Ubuntu 9.10. Is there a way to append user_xattr to the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

When you determine the correct set up for CalendarServer, we encourage you to share it with others in our community [wiki].[1](http://wiki.mediatemple.net)